# How to use OAuth2 to implement a third-party login/register?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Here is my plan (authorization code flow) of implementing such login/register logic. (**The third-party only provided the OAuth2 API**)

First the SPA frontend will send a GET request to the third-party

```
GET https://www.example.com/oauth2
client_id=dummyclient
redirect_uri=https://mysite/callback
response_type=code
scope=openid
```

Then if the user agree to give his/her openid to mysite then the fronend will get a 301 HTTP response.

```
---> 301 https://mysite/callback?code=dummycode
```

Then the browser will redirect the page to `mysite/callback` and it will reload SPA and expose the code in URL which can be captured by the SPA then it will send the code to the real backend callback.

```
GET https://mysite/api/real-callback?code=dummycode
```

When the backend get the code, it will send the code to the third-party to exchange an `access_token`. When the backend get the `access_token`, it will fire an API request to get the user's openid then decide whether to let the user login or register as a new user. At last it will give back a HTTP response to our SPA frontend which contains the `access_token` in **my** OAuth2 system or a 401 unauthorized response.

So my question is how to prove that the real callback is invoked by **my** own clients (Because if some attacker get my frontend embedded `client_id` then he can fake the OAuth2 request and phishing the user to agree. After that the attacker will get a valid code then he send back the code to my real callback. Finally, he will get the user's `access_token` in my system.) How can I use OAuth2 to do authentication without the end user's providing additional information like password.

Comment: What's your reason for not having the `real-callback` URL as a redirect URL from the OAuth2 server? I don't see any reason for getting the auth code to the SPA frontend.

Comment: @JánHalaša Even without this step the security problem still exists as long as I send back my system's `access_token` to the frontend after the third-party's OAuth2 callback request. The reason I designed the real-callback is I want to achieve the real separation between frontend and backend.

Comment: And what do you need the `access_token` for in the SPA?

Comment: @JánHalaša I used it for authorized API requests and the `access_token` is just like some kind of API key. Every API request I will add an HTTP header `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to change the OAuth2 flow to Implicit and ask for both `access_token` and `id_token` (OpenID Connect). Your SPA will get the tokens, send the ID token to your backend, which can use it to decide whether it's possible to create such user. The SPA can use the access token to call protected resources.

This way,

- only the SPA will be an OAuth2 client - tokens will not be used by two applications (SPA and backend),
- you will have just one redirect URI,
- you will not need to transfer tokens from the backend to the SPA.

**Update: Without OpenID Connect**

If you cannot use the `id_token`, you could send the `access_token` to your backend and the backend can get the user's username by sending to token to the Introspection endpoint https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662 (from the response `username` attribute). The `username` attribute is optional. Your OAuth2 server may return even more info (such as name and email).

This Introspection endpoint requires authentication, so to use it, your backend will have to be a registered OAuth2 client with its own `client_id` and a secret.